# Storing two x86 32 bit registers into 128 bit xmm register

Tags: assembly, x86, simd, sse

Is there any faster method to store two x86 32 bit registers in one 128 bit xmm register?

```
movd  xmm0, edx
movd  xmm1, eax
pshufd xmm0, xmm0, $1
por   xmm0, xmm1
```

So if EAX is `0x12345678` and EDX is `0x87654321`, the result in xmm0 must be `0x8765432112345678`.

Comment: Wow! That's a cool assembler...last I looked at was 32bit...Didn't know you could buy a 128bit pc... :P :)

Comment: Streaming SIMD Extensions (SSE) is a SIMD instruction set extension to the x86 architecture, designed by Intel and introduced in 1999.

Comment: Up to what SSE instruction set version is permissible?

Comment: @PhiS as lower as possible. :) Hmmm... At least 5 year ago, SSE2 is quite good.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With SSE 4.1 you can use `movd xmm0, eax` / `pinsrd xmm0, edx, 1` and do it in 2 instructions.

For older CPUs you can use 2 x `movd` and then `punpckldq` for a total of 3 instructions:

```
movd xmm0, edx
movd xmm1, eax
punpckldq xmm0, xmm1
```

Comment: Thanks. But this is relatively new extension set, since 2007 and the speed and code size is nearly the same.

Comment: OK - have now added a 3 instruction sequence for SSE2/SSE3.

Comment: With SSE4.1, the first instruction should still be `movd`.  The only reason to ever write `pinsrd x,r, 0` is when you really want to *merge* with the old value, instead of zero-extending into the whole register to break the dependency on the old value.  `pinsrd` decodes to 2 uops on Intel CPUs: int->xmm and shuffle, so it's more compact and doesn't need a scratch register, but on most CPUs basically runs the same as the SSE2 version.

Comment: You don't have to worry about this with intrinsics, because compilers know to use `movd` when possible.  (Comes up more often with extract, where `_mm_extract_epi32(v, 0)` compiles to `movd`.  The pinsrd intrinsic needs an extra source vector which hopefully makes most people realize they shouldn't use it.)

Comment: @PeterCordes, thanks, created another missing optimization issue (some compilers don't https://godbolt.org/z/r7oe1fG8T)

Comment: @AlexGuteniev: Oh yeah, MSVC and ICC generally don't optimize intrinsics at all, but yeah when there's a 1:1 alternative with a feature requirement that's a subset of the normal instruction for the intrinsic, it would be a good idea.  GCC and clang optimize intrinsics the same way they don't always compile `+` to an `add` instruction.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about MMX, but perhaps you want the PACKSSDW instruction.

> The PACKSSDW instruction takes the two
> double words in the source operand and
> the two double words in the
> destination operand and converts these
> to four signed words via saturation.
> The instruction packs these four words
> together and stores the result in the
> destination MMX register.

(from http://webster.cs.ucr.edu/AoA/Windows/HTML/TheMMXInstructionSeta2.html)

Edit: I just realized that those were SSE registers. Oh well.

Comment: I like xmm registers instead mmx (64bit) because they don't need 'emms' instruction after using it.